# Dump list of users to website?

Tags: meteor-useraccounts, simpleusers

I have excel sheet list of user accounts that I need to export to website.

Userid, first name, last name,

I can log into website and create accounts manually, is there any quick tool in can use to accomplish the same task?

You need to log into website, user accounts and create accounts from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [GhostInspector](https://ghostinspector.com/) in the past. It is a browser automation tool that is fairly easy for end-users to use. It can use variables in it's test steps, and these variables can come from a CSV file (spreadsheet software can typically export to CSV)

If you're a little more programming capable, you could also use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) and code your own browser automations. There are plenty of docs out there for that.

Comment: I was able to locate HP UFT tool that is able to write to website and generate report. This helps with my question.